# Jquery Remove special symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I remove `£` from a string. I was trying this:

```
price = data.salesPrice;
price = price.replace(/\^£/,"");
console.log(price);
```

but still I was receiving like this: `£22.80`. I tried with `parseInt` but it's return `NaN`. Any idea please ?

Comment: the special char will most likely be encoded. &pound; or something

Comment: Does the string actually contain a `£`, or is it encoded, such as `&pound;22.80`?

Comment: In either case, it might be better to have a regex that isolates desired characters, rather than one that removes undesired characters.

Comment: I ain't sure :( @Rory McCrossan . How I can understand that ?

Comment: @user3850712 U haven't used jQuery anywhere ;)

Comment: Actually I was getting that data by json parsing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go with regexp removing all the other characters except numbers (and dot):

```
var price = "£22.80";
price = price.replace(/\D*/, "")
```

Comment: +1 for the whitelist approach, which is less short-sighted, depending on the context of use.

Comment: How will I get integer value if the format is like this: `"29.90 €"` . I want to remove Euro symbol.

Answer (score 5):

> I am assuming (from your regex attempt) that your objective here is to remove the pound symbol (`£`) from the *beginning* of a string.

You are escaping the caret symbol in your regex. This means you want to match a literal `^` and not use it to indicate the beginning of a string. Remove that escaping and your regex will work as expected.

```
price = price.replace(/^£/,"");
```

Comment: +1 for actually explaining what the problem was and not just posting some line of code.

Comment: Hi I tried that before but still nothing happened :(

Comment: @Bala - that's because the string you gave doesn't have that symbol at the beginning of the string. My code [does remove the leading pound sign](http://jsfiddle.net/6YSXC/25/).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
price = "£22.80";
price = price.replace("£" ,"");
console.log(price);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6YSXC/16/)

Answer (score 0):

Use unicode in this case

```
  price.replace(/\u00A3/g, '');
```